# How to make query spot only the some value in a Map inside an Array in flutter (dart)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on this project where I have to put data in maps inside in array for example:
`[{Rate: 1.3, Title: "Test",...}]`
What I would like to do to find documents which has maps inside their array with rating 1.3 and above without fetching all arrays and filtering it internally

I have tried to this

```
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("profiles")
          .where("questions", arrayContains: {"Rate": 1.3})
          .getDocuments(source: Source.serverAndCache)
```

this code actually requires me to put all map data so it could return true otherwise it will return false. What I want is just to filter data based on some of the map data

Answer (score 3):

The `arrayContains` operator checks for the complete element's presence in the array. So if your array contains an element `{Rate: 1.3, Title: "Test"}`, you need to:

```
.where("questions", arrayContains: {Rate: 1.3, Title: "Test"})
```

If you want to be able to test only for `Rate`, create an additional array `Rates` where you keep just those values. Then you can query with:

```
.where("rates", arrayContains: 1.3)
```

Comment: Thank you Frank! The idea is I want to gather data in a map and still search for it. I have a lot of inputs and its all in maps dividing them into arrays will make things a bit more complicated. Do you have another suggestion regarding that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SO's 50 point limitation, I can't add a comment to the last solution from 2019.

This does not work today:

```
.where("questions", arrayContains: {Rate: 1.3, Title: "Test"})
```

This will result in an error where Rate is undefined

My Firestore collection 'contracts' looks like this:
[Firestore Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV2Fa.png)

Visual Code
[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia3Ix.png)

I have tried many other solutions in other threads (whereIn, arrayContainsAny), but I cant figure out how to query an array that holds a series of maps (0, 1, 2 etc).

Comment: Please put up the code, rather than screenshot of the code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31476798)