# Array-contains query not working react native

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i'm implementing the array-contain query but everytime i'm trying i'm Getting blank snapshot. My code is:

```js
getStation = () => {
  const query = firebase
     .firestore()
     .collection('routes')
     .where('station', 'array-contains', 'station_name ');

  query.get().then(snapshot => {
      console.log("snapshot", snapshot);

      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        alert("eri")
        console.log("eryh", doc.data);
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });

}
```

I even tried to pass the static values but not able to get the desire value.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is a problem with typo mistake station must be stations

```
.where('station', 'array-contains', 'station_name ');
```

must be

```
 .where('stations', 'array-contains', 'station_name ');
```

I hope it will fix your problem.

**Update Answer**

There is also typo mistake in station_name you just added the space after station_name

```
.where('station', 'array-contains', 'station_name ');
```

must be

```
.where('stations', 'array-contains', 'station_name');
```

Comment: no.. this doesn't worked.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use array-contains to check for a field inside a map. This is not supported.

The array-contains can only search for a field inside the array and not a field inside a map which is inside that array.

A workaround I have tested is that you add an extra field inside the array that will be a boolean or a string and you can query based on it.

**Using a boolean field in the array:**

[image]

```
.where('stations', 'array-contains', true);
```

**Using a String field in the array:**

[image]

```
.where('stations', 'array-contains', 'station_name exists');
```

Comment: The reason you give for why OP's code doesn't work is correct, but your explanation is a bit off, and your workarounds won't work either. It's actually simpler than your explanation: `array-contains` checks if the precise object/value you specify exists in the array. It can't check on subsets of the array elements, only on complete values.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more why you believe the workarounds won't work ?

Comment: Hmm... on second reading it *might* indeed work. I was thrown off by the mixed types that you now have in your array. I'd still recommend against mixing types in this way, as it just makes debugging and maintenance harder. Separating out the precise value you want to filter on is the more idiomatic approach for this use-case.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The `array-contains` operation checks if the precise object/value you specify exists in the array. It can't check on subsets of the array elements, only on complete values. So in your current structure, you'd have to pass all properties into the `array-contains` call:

```
.where('station', 'array-contains', 
  { station_address_name: '...', station_lat_long: ..., status_name: '...' });
```

This typically is not feasible, in which case you'll want to store the elements that you want to filter on in a (additional) separate field in your documents. In this example, since you want to filter on station names, you'd add a field `station_names` where you store just the station names. Then you can query with:

```
.where('station_names', 'array-contains', 'name to search for')
```

Also see:

- [Firestore to query by an array's field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081799/firestore-to-query-by-an-arrays-field-value/54081889#54081889)
- [Firestore array-contains-any is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052349/firestore-array-contains-any-is-not-working-properly/59053018#59053018)
- [How to make query spot only the some value in a Map inside an Array in flutter (dart)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634679/how-to-make-query-spot-only-the-some-value-in-a-map-inside-an-array-in-flutter/57638766#57638766)