# react-native-firebase query with 'array-contains' in useEffect keeps refreshing component

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm just trying to make a request to fetch only the threads that contain the current user's id.

If I remove my 'where' query, I can fetch all threads.

There is my code :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore()
      .collection('THREADS')
      // query is empty
      .where('usersIds', 'array-contains', ['60ddd70c7a3a1e8e62d14dac'])
      .orderBy('latestMessage.createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const threadsQueried = querySnapshot
          ? querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
              return {
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
              };
            })
          : null;

        setThreads(threadsQueried);

        if (loading) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  });
```

I already tried without putting my id into an array, but the component keeps refreshing, like that:

```
.where('usersIds', 'array-contains', '60ddd70c7a3a1e8e62d14dac')
```

My firebase datas:

[image: Firebase]

I already check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59053018/9300663

and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215461/9300663

Edit: So it is working when id is without brackets ('60ddd70c7a3a1e8e62d14dac') into the query

But my component keeps refreshing.

If I add an empty array or an array with dependencies to my useEffect, the query does not works anymore.

Edit 2: Query is working but get called two times and the second time get back with 'null', which is emptying my state.

[image: With and without 'where' query]

Comment: As written in the document the correct query is .where('usersIds', 'array-contains', '60ddd70c7a3a1e8e62d14dac') without the brakets. What error are you getting with this query?

Comment: What error is thrown in the console? What isn't working exactly? Is it the response from Firestore query or something with react ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's working without brackets, but the component keeps refreshing

Comment: It's not possible that the query stop to work if you put a dependency array in useEffect. However the correct implementation is to put an empty array in useEffect as a dependency, in this way the code inside useEffect will be executed just once when the component is mounted

Comment: Ok, so if I add or not an empty array, and console.log the querySnapshot, I get first the right querySnapshot, then 'null'.

That's why my state get overwritten by 'null'.

Like every time the query is launched 2 times.

But without the 'where' query, I get only one response, not 2.

Comment: Try to use forEach (https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querysnapshot), I worked a lot with firestore, but I have never seen docs.map. querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
              return {
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
              };
            })
and try to share your whole component if you want help

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution when I tried another way to get my firebase query by using get() instead of onSnapshot():

```
firestore()
      .collection('THREADS')
      .where('usersIds', 'array-contains', user.id)
      .orderBy('latestMessage.createdAt', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const threadsQueried = querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
          return {
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          };
        });
        setThreads(threadsQueried);
```

The problem with 'get()' was that the query only worked once and didn't update if new threads were created.

But it allowed me to have a firebase error asking me to create the indexes: 'usersIds' and 'latestMessage.createdAt'. After creating them, I was able to reuse my old code and everything's working correctly now.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore()
      .collection('THREADS')
      .where('usersIds', 'array-contains', user.id)
      .orderBy('latestMessage.createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const threadsQueried = querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
          return {
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          };
        });
        setThreads(threadsQueried);
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```